# How can I exactly match routes nested deeply in react router 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I match the full route with path "users/:id/settings" but at the same time render only the component in each path:

- /users -> only renders a list of users
- /users/:id -> only renders the user profile
- /users/:id/settings -> only renders the user settings.

```
     <Route path="users" element={<h2>LIST PROJECTS</h2>}>
       <Route path=":id" element={<h2>PROJECT id</h2>}>
          <Route path="settings" element={<h2>PROJECT SETTINGS</h2>} />
        </Route>
     </Route>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved this by:

1. Creating index routes ("/") to encapsulate the children like so:

```
    - /              // Level 1 routes index route
    - users          // level 1 route
       - /             // Level 2 routes index route                  
       - :id           // level 2 route
       - settings      // level 2 route

    - posts          // level 1 route
       - /             // Level 2 routes index route
       - :id           // level 2 route
       - settings      // level 2 route
       - ...
```

I think of Level 1 routes as my app's data collections *(users, posts etc)* and level 2 routes as any sub-routes that relate to a specific item within that higher level collection *(:userId, settings etc)*

2. Using the `<Outlet />` component from react-router-v6 as the element to-be-rendered in each parent route. The [Outlet is responsible for rendering all the children](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#outlet) components of the children routes under that index, so we use `element={<Outlet />}` on the index route instead of rendering a React component directly.

Here is an example with index routes rendering an Outlet component:

```
          <Route path="users"element={ <Outlet /> } >
            <Route path="/" element={<h2>LIST USERS</h2>} />
            <Route path=":id" >
               <Route path="/" element={<React.Fragment>
                                         <h2>USER id</h2>
                                         <Outlet />
                                       </React.Fragment>} />
               <Route path="settings" element={<h2>USER SETTINGS</h2>} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
```

Here is a more complete approach using the useRoutes hook with which we can write the same configuration more cleanly as a simple JS object:

```
    import {Outlet, useRoutes} from "react-router-dom"
    
    const App = () => {

      let routeElement = useRoutes([
        {
          path: "/",
          element: <GlobalPageTemplate />,
          children: [
            {
              path: "users",
              element: <Outlet />,
              children: [
                { path: "/", element:<h1>LIST USERS <h1/> },
                {
                  path: "/:id",
                  children: [
                    { path: "/", element: <h1>USER ID</h1> },
                    { path: "/settings", element: <h1>USER SETTINGS</h1> },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              path: "posts",
              element: <Outlet />,
              children: [
                { path: "/", element: <h1>LIST POSTS</h1> },
                {
                  path: "/:id",
                  children: [
                    { path: "/", element: <h1>POST ID</h1> },
                    { path: "/settings", element: <h1>POST SETTINGS</h1> },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              path: "teams",
              element: <Outlet />,
              children: [
                { path: "/", element: <h1>LIST TEAMS</h1> },
                {
                  path: "/:id",
                  children: [
                    { path: "/", element: <h1>TEAMS ID</h1> },
                    { path: "/settings", element: <h1>TEAM SETTINGS</h1> },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ]
        }
      ]);
    
      return routeElement
    }
```

Comment: Things may've be different a year ago when still in beta, but note that currently for all your "index" routes  on `path: "/"` you can simply use `index: true`. Also, the parent routes will render an `Outlet` component by default if there is no `element` property provided.

Answer (score -3):

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
<BrowserRouter>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          component={Home}
          
        />
        <Route exact path="/user" component={User} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/user/:id/setting"
          render={(props) => {
            return <Your Component {...props} />;
          }}
        />
       
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

//in your component
// AllProduct is from database or the items you want to match import it 1st

```
let component = (props) => {
  let compo= props.location.state;
//if state is undefined can be access with params
if (!compo) {
const id = props.match.params.id;
compo = AllProduct.find((items) => items.id == id);
```

}

Comment: Note you are using react router v5 not 6. In react-router-v6, the Switch is no longer used. You need to replace all your Switch components with Routes components. Any routes wrapped with a Routes component, are automatically relative to the parent route. Here is a great guide in the docs for migrating from v5 to v6: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes